# Looping Logical Error

Tags: java, list, loops

I got a table with values - Username, Brand and Company with details in the table

[image]

Now i am trying to iterate through loop to print the name of the user with Brand / Name of the user and with company.

But when i try this in the loop, i am not getting the proper output..

```
 public static void main(String arfs[])
 {
    List company = new ArrayList();
    List brand = new ArrayList();
    List name = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL","root","root");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from fashion");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        name.add(rs.getString("Username"));
        brand.add(rs.getString("Brand"));
        company.add(rs.getString("Company"));
    }



    for(int i=0; i<name.size();i++)
    {
        if((name.get(i)!=null)&&(brand.get(i)!=null))
        {
            System.out.println("----Brand------");
            System.out.println(brand.get(i));

        }
        if((name.get(i)!=null)&&(company.get(i)!=null))
        {
             System.out.println("----Company-----");
            System.out.println(company.get(i));
        }

    }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

When i run this code, only the Brand gets printed and not the company..can anyone help me out..?

Comment: I see that first two companies are `null`. So the condition is evaluated to `false`..

Comment: company can be null in the arraylist!!!

Comment: Can we see the actual output?

Comment: Agree with  @KumaresanPerumal  Those if condtions are blocking the output. So remove those. Also don't keep a name as a primary key. (If the username is primary key).

Comment: As others wrote, problem is in your If conditions (it's pure logic, while field is null, that will dont print anything) 

Btw I also think that logic to save 1 each row of the table in 3 separate Lists is not good idea .. 

Better will be eg.  make own class and that save into List, or Map,  other way can be via one List of array eg. (each record will be as 1 row), etc. ..

Comment: As asked by others, provide actual output. You can restructure your ifs inside for loop as ,`if(name.get(i)!=null){ if(brand.get(i)!=null){...}if(company.get(i)!=null){...}}`

Comment: received the output!  thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove your condition. your company field is null,so 'if' condition does print anything.

```
for(int i=0; i<name.size();i++)
    {

            System.out.println("----Brand------");
            System.out.println(brand.get(i));
            System.out.println("----Company-----");
            System.out.println(company.get(i));

    }
```